# How can I see/understand what Windows Installer auto-rollback is (or isn't) doing?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer, event-log, repair-install

I'm a developer working on a cross-platform application. One of the target platforms is Windows, and I've inherited an installer written using Wix.

One of our current priorities is recoverability from failures that occur during the process of upgrading to a new version of our application. It's a background application controlled by a server component, and an important capability is that it upgrade itself without user supervision.

So, our QE folks are hammering on this functionality, and I'm working on a bug report stating that the installation is left in an invalid state if machine gets restarted at a certain point during the installation process. Since the user doesn't know the upgrade is happening (and that's what our customers want), it's entirely feasible that they might choose to restart at exactly the wrong time.

In this specific case the machine is running Windows 10. At the moment, I suspect that the built-in automatic rollback functionality is doing something here, either during shutdown or upon startup, but I don't know how to prove it, as all of the code I control is getting killed before any of this happens. Is there a log file somewhere that will show me what steps were taken by the automatic recovery mechanism? Or a particular place to look in Event Viewer? I know when it happened within a minute or so; I just don't know where to look.

All of my attempts to Google for this information are cluttered up with dozens of articles about getting into and out of self-repair *loops*, which is not at all what I'm after. I just want to know what the repair mechanism is doing so that I can try to understand how my test machine is getting into the invalid state.

I've dug around for hours in the Event Log to no avail, but I'm not sure I know the right place to look.

I can reproduce this easily, so if I have to enable some kind of logging somehow and then do it again, that's fine.

Comment: Windows Installer does write to the event log. Rather than looking for things related to auto-rollback, have you looked for what Windows Installer DOES write to Event Logs regarding the transaction?

Comment: Does your installer write any logs of its own, separate from the Event Viewer, or the Windows Installer logs?

Comment: Where exactly would I find the events Installer wrote itself? Event Viewer is a labyrinth to me. My installer does create a log of its own, and nothing appears at any appoint after I trigger the restart.

Comment: Here's Microsoft's guide, found with a simple web search, for Windows Installer Event Logging. I'd guess this is as good a place as any to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/event-logging

Comment: I found that page in my searches before posting. I found only one installer-related entry, stating that it was beginning a Windows installer transaction, followed by a couple events triggered by some of my postinstall actions (e.g. installation of a service). Nothing about rollback -- unless those would be buried in the massive tree of folders under Application and Service Logs? (If so, any directions would be much appreciated.)

Comment: I've now learned that, upon reboot, my installation was not rolled back, but [suspended](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-fix-a-suspended-installation-on-windows-10/aa64f913-ac0d-42b2-b31f-27fde0c6ff80). As that's quite different than the question I asked here, I think my question should be closed.

Comment: You can close/delete your own question, if you wish to do that. The Community has to get 5 votes to close a question, but the person who asked it is able to do it on their own preference.

Comment: I would prefer close over delete. Looks like closing my own question requires 250 reputation; I’m not a heavy user and fall a bit short of that at the moment. Voting to close requires 3,000 and is completely out of the question.

Comment: Got it. It's got 4 close votes currently, so it should be closed relatively soon.